# Analysing line by line and storing if meets criteria, else ignore

Tags: c#, filter, streamreader

I've dug around a lot on this one and not found quite was I was looking for.

INPUT: Multiple (in the hundreds, occasionally thousands) of lines of ASCII text, ranging from 97 characters long to over 500. The criteria for whether I want to keep this data or not is purely contained in the first 3 characters (always numbers - arbitrary values 100,200 and 300 are the ones I'm interested in).

The output required is only those that start with 100, 200 or 300, the rest I can ignore.

This is what I have as my streamreader, which currently outputs to console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
public void Do
{

    // Read in a file line-by-line, and store in a List.

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("File.dat"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(line); // Add to list.
            Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
        //    Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I was hoping to put in a line that says

```
IF {
FIRST3CHAR != (100,200,300) }
then skip,
```

but I'm unsure how to define the FIRST3CHAR class. This is the only filter that will be done on the raw data.

I will afterwards, be analysing this filtered data set based on other criteria contained within, but I'll give that a shot myself before asking for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't just add this condition to your loop?

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var beginning = line.Substring(0, 3);
    if(beginning != "100" && beginning != "200" && beginning != "300")
        continue;
    list.Add(line); // Add to list.
    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is more readable and does what you want:

```
var allowedNumbers = new[]{ "100", "200", "300" };
IEnumerable<String> lines = File
                   .ReadLines("File.dat")
                   .Where(l => allowedNumbers.Any(num => l.StartsWith(num)));
```

now you can enumerate the lines for example with a `foreach`:

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
}
```

Since you want to add those lines to a `List<string>` anyway, you can use `Enumerable.ToList` instead of the `foreach`:

```
List<string> list = lines.ToList();
```

Comment: Sweet solution but potential bottleneck.

Comment: @PLB: Where do you see a bottleneck? Note that [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) doesn't read the whole file into the memory before returning the result. See the *Remarks* section of its documentation for more information.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `Where` will iterate over read lines, and `any` will iterate over `allowedMembers`. While this could be done in on loop. I don't say that this is a bad solution. Don't get me wrong. :)

Comment: @PLB: How would you do that in one loop?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth With taking first 3 characters from line in while loop and check it in `if`.

Comment: @PLB: I assume that you haven't got the point of _deferred execution_. Understand `Where` as an `if`-clause in a loop and not as additional loop. `Any` used as above is the same as Marc Gravells `||` approach.

Comment: it would not cause a bottleneck but would would save only `memory` not `speed`..and i guess memory is not an issue here since his text file would hardly exceed `2mb`..reading the whole file into memory would be good choice here since anyway you have 2 read all the lines

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Why is it better to read all lines into memory even those that you are not interested in? `File.ReadLines` is working like a `StreamReader` which is what OP is using anyway. It skips lines which don't start with "100","200" or "300".

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest level:

```
if(line.StartsWith("100") || line.StartsWith("200") || line.StartsWith("300"))
{
    list.Add(line); // Add to list.
    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
}
```

If the file is huge (as in, hundreds of thousands of lines), it might also be worth looking at implementing it as an iterator block. But the "starts" test is pretty simple.

If you need more flexibility, I would consider a regex; for example:

```
static readonly Regex re = new Regex("^[012]00", RegexOptions.Compiled);

...
while (...)
{
    if(re.IsMatch(line))
    {
        list.Add(line); // Add to list.
        Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you might consider to fill a StringBuilder for the output, if it's not necessary to have it in real-time

Comment: @trippino we don't know what the OP is using the list for; I don't think stringbuilder applies here. The console looks like a UI tracer to me - probably fine to keep that "as is"

Comment: yep it was just an hint to debug faster

Comment: The next step is for each 100 starting line, to find the digits in the locations 40-45 and subtotal them by the variables that are in character location 20-23, for each line with 200 (and subtotal by the variables in 24-26, go to 50-55 and for 300, 27-29, go to 60-65 etc. The final output will be these totals subgrouped into the respective sorts in 20-23 etc.) per 100, 200 and 300 starting digits.